# Gravity forms customize field markup for the same form appearing in different places

Tags: shortcode, plugin-gravity-forms

I know i can customize the markup for a gravity form field using their `gform_field_input` filter. Is there a a

```php
add_filter( 'gform_field_input', 'my_gf_inputs', 10, 5 );
function my_gf_inputs( $input, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id ) {
    if ($field->formId == 1){ //the form i'm customizing

        switch( $field->id ){
            case 1: //email field in that form
            $input = <<<INPUT
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="input_1" id="input_1_1" type="text" value="" placeholder="name" class="form-control" tabindex="1" aria-invalid="false">
    </div>
</div>
INPUT;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way i can produce different markup for the same form? That is, suppose it appears in both the header and the footer of a page but in a different design. Is there a way i can use the [shortcode](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/shortcodes/#form-shortcode) to indicate that? for example by adding an arbitrary key/value parameter like say, "position", like this?

`[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false" position="header"]`

`[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false" position="footer"]`

and then use `position`s value in the filter for different markup?

Answer (score 1):

You have three ways:

1) To find out the correct hook (at this moment i can tell if it even exists for that)

2) To use only CSS (For example, just target your first form with `#header .form-group{}` ( or by its another parent div, instead of `#header` )

3) Use the GLOBAL variable to count each time whenever that function executes. i.e, see example:

```
add_filter( ........... );
function ..........{
    $GLOBALS['my_form_counter'] = empty($GLOBALS['my_form_counter']) ? 1 : $GLOBALS['my_form_counter'] + 1;
    if($GLOBALS['my_form_counter'] == 1){
       //it's the first time of the form EXECUTION, so you know where it is happening.. Code what you want
    }

    if($GLOBALS['my_form_counter'] == 2){
       //it's the second time of the form EXECUTION, so do now what you want
    }
}
```